# fmt with Howard Hinnant's date: why "{}" from fmt::to_string? Best practice for fmt and date?

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono, fmt

TL;DR: I am implementing custom formatter for [fmt](https://fmt.dev/dev/api.html) and Howard Hinnant's [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library. With `date::year_month_day d{};`, why does `fmt::to_string(d)` return `"{}"` while `fmt::format("{}", d)` works fine, returning `"0000-00-00"`? [Example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJN5b0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTOkADqgWF1tPYYmZrxePmp0NnaORi5ukorKmKp%2BDATMxAQBxqbmCSrhtKnpBJEOzq7uCmkZWUG5VcWl0bFmAJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzFhUtpgA1ABiALIAKgD6ABLYAIIAItgASnMA8vZWAJriAAzLg7bIhlhj4gM6VEYEAPQ0xEbMBAB0CDfYx6eSA3Ol3GNx0CAIBA8ChAj0exGYAHcPsBCAgDE4DEpunQCFpPmgjI8FqgEel0AtbLQRE90O9MI83lVXI8gQYsI9abiOXSvj8/n9cUYPMJcaC%2BScqsQDKoxvcCCAQC83hDXKDORwQABPTDpOZGHEIOa0zU/a4AdlkJzG1rGguFdNBBE1Hi0zCM4wACuklHp6JgAB4EcXLG1jZgGIhjDzezAQL3EH04gMEa6SABsY1U/ta5ukY2ImAIXVomYI/o%2BLhRtAgrRuefEZtW/KtNrtIswjudrvdkxIyt9uMDwdD4cjSveEDQtCqY3VCu1uv19ENxtTGc1RnQpF7r3eA%2BTa9L2bGAFpTVgLk6XZOyx9OgQazmG5aQ6GbVOZ7YUwviNcBqsxggL9Wg3dAPh/Gs6z%2BN93zoGcDGnPBgDsdAxiXAgED/ACIAQnxkMwdAQM3D50IQSCBhfGDrQ/FNcKQlDZ2YTUsMAuj8MI0CPmNcjKKogsi2IEs5QVccCDmIgb3Le8a23KRJGfEAjm4BtVjPC1FPkxs1OkDSVLk7cf23Ujt2NWsKOgm09JOPTzOsiUCClGUAEcEQ7C0bJfAVMCFdsxQGX57MclNhMVPt3lxYhQRcjt/NzCzrTbB1bivbtPRjfch38%2BKwwjVAoxjON0qTQNDyzJ8LXzQtiyPCtMCrHjzSbOzXwS7z7VFZKuypHsJjCzJiqDLKW2tUc8tEyc4JTaLDyc7det3fq/RKqQMzK09zySVgUsku8I0fOLhrffjqpC0TxNQHbpPaVN5IAVmkaLxFuptJEkMzeOtKzTkbKDmq/NDmFsGsDpasZYVlB4FSIOZJVsYBgaoQHWGhMYFAQTpWFQ47BJuo48aOE88cJo45LGDEU2x6cbufPTXrGWwmWYdBspCjxiC/CA5Jpn7bp0Wh9Ih%2BUQGh2HRAgOctR1Yg9QNI0mO51ZWne5tQfBkKRYcuHgYREgAGsFFlUYxgRVFbVsZjkExIgjFRhzpXlKN2foA2ufux7nq5w7Wadh8ufcnm%2BYF9XUBhzWxce/3FeV5rQzVyGQDZ/6SEFkS%2BuN1F7xT4WQ9F%2BGcx14hdbDA3XNYVht0T%2Bg4dx/HieJz3Qe9jm/dkH7XpMul5ylmXlzlk1I%2Bj76muWXp2lYEBelu3pSFMXojmn1AJ50OQ5FRzpuhBAFOGn%2BU59H9pdZAAZbo%2BW6BgADgvgY0wGV7JFuyRz6ECfuGn2f59IRfemn6EjlIXf57tDgLAJABIPB4HYGQCgE0hQQIqMATgRxOCkBGFtVw0IIBOAnh/Jwth0iagntvUgBJ3T0G2LQVgBC96kCwG8UQ7BsHT3wAWZIAA3TA0JqEBiSBGPoH8vzKEYUIPATh4TEE1HoLAhCd7syMIw9oNB6BMDYBwHg/BBDCFECgFeMhhFOGhLAbqHA5SkHYW4XoaZJDbyVp/DwBROE/0SMkDQEBLC1FMMgywTRyhuGQaEXwdB3GCH8QUbxMQKjIKUPkFI1R%2BqBA8XkJIBQigZDCS0SJsSgkZMaKMZoET2gKHXj0LgY8J5TxnkIr%2B/pz5phPGmbgYxgDIGQGMRBHxOCAVwIQZOgxkFjD0LAyBqYBicBzMvGQcgd7yIPkfTg7TH6PwGEcAY3BVmcAGAATlus/Xor8KnUK/j/RS/95GkGAYgEA94PARnIJQMBcDfGkAIt0x5ijGAsAYWohE8IPDSNKZPN%2BlSJ69PThhMY1Tan1Mac01pRx2lTL3jYw%2BAwBgfBReijFmKdl7PfgvCeRy/4AP3jsyQgKDn4pOYi9oZifAaG4EAA%3D).

---

I'm using [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library and trying to switch from iostreams to [fmt](https://fmt.dev/dev/api.html). I need to format `date::year_month_day` in YYYY-MM-DD format so I wrote a custom formatter (template specialization of fmt::formatter for `date::year_month_day`):

```
template<>
struct fmt::formatter<date::year_month_day> {
    template<typename ParseContext>
    auto parse(ParseContext & ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }

    template<typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const date::year_month_day & ymd, FormatContext & ctx) -> decltype(ctx.out()) {
        const int year = (int)ymd.year();
        const unsigned month = (unsigned)ymd.month();
        const unsigned day = (unsigned)ymd.day();
        return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{:04}-{:02}-{:02}", year, month, day);
    }
};
```

Complete minimal working example, with two working examples and one failing, is [available on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJN5b0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTOkADqgWF1tPYYmZrxePmp0NnaORi5ukorKmKp%2BDATMxAQBxqbmCSrhtKnpBJEOzq7uCmkZWUG5VcWl0bFmAJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzFhUtpgA1ABiALIAKgD6ABLYAIIAItgASnMA8vZWAJriAAzLg7bIhlhj4gM6VEYEAPQ0xEbMBAB0CDfYx6eSA3Ol3GNx0CAIBA8ChAj0exGYAHcPsBCAgDE4DEpunQCFpPmgjI8FqgEel0AtbLQRE90O9MI83lVXI8gQYsI9abiOXSvj8/n9cUYPMJcaC%2BScqsQDKoxvcCCAQC83hDXKDORwQABPTDpOZGHEIOa0zU/a4AdlkJzG1rGguFdNBBE1Hi0zCM4wACuklHp6JgAB4EcXLG1jZgGIhjDzezAQL3EH04gMEa6SABsY1U/ta5ukY2ImAIXVomYI/o%2BLhRtAgrRuefEZtW/KtNrtIswjudrvdkxIyt9uMDwdD4cjSveEDQtCqY3VCu1uv19ENxtTGc1RnQpF7r3eA%2BTa9L2bGAFpTVgLk6XZOyx9OgQazmG5aQ6GbVOZ7YUwviNcBqsxggL9Wg3dAPh/Gs6z%2BN93zoGcDGnPBgDsdAxiXAgED/ACIAQnxkMwdAQM3D50IQSCBhfGDrQ/FNcKQlDZ2YTUsMAuj8MI0CPmNcjKKogsi2IEs5QVccCDmIgb3Le8a23KRJGfEAjm4BtVjPC1FPkxs1OkDSVLk7cf23Ujt2NWsKOgm09JOPTzOsiUCClGUAEcEQ7C0bJfAVMCFdsxQGX57MclNhMVPt3lxYhQRcjt/NzCzrTbB1bivbtPRjfch38%2BKwwjVAoxjON0qTQNDyzJ8LXzQtiyPCtMCrHjzSbOzXwS7z7VFZKuypHsJjCzJiqDLKW2tUc8tEyc4JTaLDyc7det3fq/RKqQMzK09zySVgUsku8I0fOLhrffjqpC0TxNQHbpPaVN5IAVmkaLxFuptJEkMzeOtKzTkbKDmq/NDmFsGsDpasZYVlB4FSIOZJVsYBgaoQHWGhMYFAQTpWFQ47BJuo48aOE88cJo45LGDEU2x6cbufPTXrGWwmWYdBspCjxiC/CA5Jpn7bp0Wh9Ih%2BUQGh2HRAgOctR1Yg9QNI0mO51ZWne5tQfBkKRYcuHgYREgAGsFFlUYxgRVFbVsZjkExIgjFRhzpXlKN2foA2ufux7nq5w7Wadh8ufcnm%2BYF9XUBhzWxce/3FeV5rQzVyGQDZ/6SEFkS%2BuN1F7xT4WQ9F%2BGcx14hdbDA3XNYVht0T%2Bg4dx/HieJz3Qe9jm/dkH7XpMul5ylmXlzlk1I%2Bj76muWXp2lYEBelu3pSFMXojmn1AJ50OQ5FRzpuhBAFOGn%2BU59H9pdZAAZbo%2BW6BgADgvgY0wGV7JFuyRz6ECfuGn2f59IRfemn6EjlIXf57tDgLAJABIPB4HYGQCgE0hQQIqMATgRxOCkBGFtVw0IIBOAnh/Jwth0iagntvUgBJ3T0G2LQVgBC96kCwG8UQ7BsHT3wAWZIAA3TA0JqEBiSBGPoH8vzKEYUIPATh4TEE1HoLAhCd7syMIw9oNB6BMDYBwHg/BBDCFECgFeMhhFOGhLAbqHA5SkHYW4XoaZJDbyVp/DwBROE/0SMkDQEBLC1FMMgywTRyhuGQaEXwdB3GCH8QUbxMQKjIKUPkFI1R%2BqBA8XkJIBQigZDCS0SJsSgkZMaKMZoET2gKHXj0LgY8J5TxnkIr%2B/pz5phPGmbgYxgDIGQGMRBHxOCAVwIQZOgxkFjD0LAyBqYBicBzMvGQcgd7yIPkfTg7TH6PwGEcAY3BVmcAGAATlus/Xor8KnUK/j/RS/95GkGAYgEA94PARnIJQMBcDfGkAIt0x5ijGAsAYWohE8IPDSNKZPN%2BlSJ69PThhMY1Tan1Mac01pRx2lTL3jYw%2BAwBgfBReijFmKdl7PfgvCeRy/4AP3jsyQgKDn4pOYi9oZifAaG4EAA%3D).

Using that custom formatter, `fmt::format("{}", date::year_month_day{})` works as expected, returning `"0000-00-00"`. `fmt::to_string(date::year_month_day{})` is supposed to return the same result, but returns `"{}"` instead.

What is the best way of formatting `date::year_month_day` and other types from `date` with `fmt`, including `fmt::to_string()`? Why do I get that `"{}"`?

I can't use compiler with C++20 date support yet: as far as I know, there are no complete implementations of calendar and timezone parts of C++20's std::chrono as of June 2020.

Update: using custom formatter for custom empty struct works fine, giving the same result for `format("{}", s)` and `to_string(s)`, see examples on the godbolt link above. So there must be something special about `date::year_month_day` which breaks `fmt::to_string()`.

Comment: According to your godbolt in `fmt::to_string(date::year_month_day{})` `to_string` is calling `date::format<byte, date::year_month_day>(byte const, date::year_month_day const&)decltype ((to_stream((declval<std::basic_ostream<byte, std::char_traits<byte> >&>)(), {parm#1}, {parm#2})),std::__cxx11::basic_string<byte, std::char_traits<byte>, std::::allocator<byte> >{})`. It seems that the compiler finds multiple matching overloads and does not select the one that you want.

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks! That's interesting because `byte` isn't explicitly mentioned anywhere in `fmt` or `date` (or in sample code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an unfortunate effect of the argument-dependent lookup: `fmt::to_string` calls `format` which ends up being resolved to `date::format` instead of `fmt::format`. The fix is to fully qualify the call to `format` in `fmt::to_string` since it depends on a user-defined type.

Update: this has been fixed in https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/2cac8a9d2e36cd920a9a60ec5b776c187e843fbb.

Comment: Thanks! Would you accept a pull request with that two-line fix? (two because to_string and to_wstring) I discovered this fix yesterday and it works for me (tm), but I did not check whether it breaks any fmt tests or other use cases. Also, this reminds me of someone's talk (Titus Winters?) advising to avoid identifiers without namespace qualifier in large codebases.